# Why is mp4 audio behaving weirdly in Firefox + videojs player?

Tags: javascript, firefox, audio, video, video.js

I am testing a 5 min 36 second Mp4 video in the [videojs player](http://www.videojs.com/) in various browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE-11 on Windows; Chrome, Safari and Opera on iOS). Only in Firefox are there the following problems:

- 42 seconds into the video the audio stops and does not resume

OR

- at 42 seconds, the audio stops and the last 30 seconds of audio (i.e., from 5:04s to 5:35s) plays, then stops, and the video continues in silence.

NB: This happens in Firefox off and on, and only with this mp4. Sometimes it works fine (both locally and off the server), other times it has one of the problems above. The usual sign of trouble is that the video does  not start loading immediately, there is a wait of about 10 seconds; if it starts loading immediately, the audio plays fine. All other mp4s I have play with no audio problem in Firefox. If I open the problem-file directly in the Firefox native player, no problem (but have only tested twice).